# WooCommerce Variable Product notice Issue - please choose product options

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

I'm  building an e-commerce site. I'm having some trouble with WooCommerce **Variable Product**.

The "Add to Cart" button works fine with simple products, but does not work with variable products. It gives a `"Please choose product options…"` notice.

I looked everywhere and tried several suggestions online, none of them work. So I looked into WooCommerce source file: **`class-wc-form-handler.php`**.

In the function **`add_to_cart_handler_variable`**:

```
function add_to_cart_handler_variable( $product_id ) {
    $adding_to_cart     = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $variation_id       = empty( $_REQUEST['variation_id'] ) ? '' : absint( $_REQUEST['variation_id'] );
    $quantity           = empty( $_REQUEST['quantity'] ) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount( $_REQUEST['quantity'] );
    $missing_attributes = array();
    $variations         = array();
    $attributes         = $adding_to_cart->get_attributes();
    $variation          = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
...
if ( $missing_attributes ) {
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( _n( '%s is a required field', '%s are required fields', sizeof( $missing_attributes ), 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $missing_attributes ) ), 'error' );
    } elseif ( empty( $variation_id ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please choose product options&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    } else {
        // Add to cart validation
        $passed_validation  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variations );

        if ( $passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variations ) !== false ) {
            wc_add_to_cart_message( $product_id );
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The error is caught in the elseif clause. 
So I tried to echo out `$variation_id`, `$variations`, and `$variation`. None of them has anything in it because when I echo `$variation_id`: it doesn't output anything.

How can the error be resolved?

Comment: Try disabling other plugins and switching to a default theme to try to isolate the problem. The variation ID is determined via javascript so if you have a script error it might not work. Also, check your browser's developer console.

Comment: @helgatheviking I did check my dev console, there is a js error, but it's not a related function

Comment: But if it breaks the JS, then the WooCommerce JS might not be running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On shop page you can't use add-to-cart button for variable products, because you need first to go on single product page to chose the options for this variable product before adding it to cart.

On variable product pages, normally you have some displayed **options to chose** for a variable product, before using "add to cart" button. If you don't do it, you get the error message… 
So at this point:

1. The options **are not displayed** in the product page (Bad settings in your backend product page, a bug with your theme or some additional plugin):

   - Check your product backend settings
   - Try to switch to default wordpress theme (to see if this issue is still there)
   - Try to disable most of all plugins.
2. the options are **displayed**: So chose your options first for this product, then add to cart

If this issue is related to your theme, contact the author of your theme and open a support thread or ticket…

---

**OUPUTTING PRODUCT VARIATIONS FOR A PRODUCT ID:**

To get product variations programmatically for a variable product ID:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

echo var_dump($product_variations); // Displaying the array
```

Then to get the first variation ID:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

$variation_product_id = $product_variations [0]['variation_id'];
echo $variation_product_id; // Displaying the variation ID
```

Or to get an array of all variations ID of this product ID:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

$arr_variations_id = array();
foreach ($product_variations as $variation) {
    $product_variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
    array_push( $arr_variations_id, $product_variation_id );
}

echo var_dump($arr_variations_id); // Displaying the array of variations ID
```

A reference :  [Change "Add to Cart" button to "Go to Product" in the Shop Page](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203006565-Change-Add-to-Cart-button-to-Go-to-Product-in-the-Shop-Page)

Comment: Thanks LogicTheAztec for the response, but I do have the displayed options to chose for the variable product. And after I choose these variables, it would still return empty

Comment: @PatDuJour as helgathevicking or my self have suggested before, It seems that you have some bug in your theme (or in some plugin may be)…

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else is building a custom theme and encounters this issue with variations not adding to the cart as expected - you may need to check your theme is loading the */woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.min.js* script - add the following to wherever you enqueue your scripts to manually add it:

```
wp_enqueue_script('wc-add-to-cart-variation');
```

This solved the issue for me.

Comment: This is an acceptable answer. Other answers provided mention disabling plugins and/or changing themes. There is no need to disable plugins or change themes when this line of code is added to your Theme "functions.php" file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While we all have variation swatches in common the error (bizarre as this sounds) lays with the theme being incompatible. To test simply switch to 2020 theme and the ordering should work. I would recommend then making 2020 suite your needs and stop using the theme where the developers take days off when woocommerce updates are rolled out! Disabling the swatches wont help as the code is already there. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. Had the same issue....deactivated the **autoptimize plugin** and the problem was solved.
2. Also,to know which plugin to disable, you can simply load the page or the website, inspect element or developers mode, then check the console to see the source of the error which you can then relate to the relevant plugin and then disable from your wp dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I use wishlist plugin and when I tried to add variable product to cart I have got: '**The selected product isn't a variation of Product name, please choose product options by visiting Product name.**'

The problem was that my product haven't default variation. So user added to wishlist product without selected variation. So when after user tries to add this product to cart error appears.

Here is FIX: just set default variation to all cariation products!
(Manually or via code). So user COULD NOT add product with EMPTY variation. Variation will be selected by default or user changes variation by himself.

So now in wishlist we have variation selected and all works as it should. It will work on all pages, archives, wishlists etc. Good luck! ;)

you’ll need to modify the functions.php file. Simply go to wp-content/yourtheme/functions.php on your child theme. Here, we’ll show you the full code and then we’ll explain its main parts. So the full PHP script to create WooCommerce default product attributes programmatically is the following:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'quadlayers_product_default_attributes');
function quadlayers_product_default_attributes() {
      global $product;
      if (!count($default_attributes = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_default_attributes'))) {
        $new_defaults = array();
        $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        if (count($product_attributes)) {
          foreach ($product_attributes as $key => $attributes) {
            $values = explode(',', $product->get_attribute($key));
            if (isset($values[0]) && !isset($default_attributes[$key])) {
              $new_defaults[$key] = sanitize_key($values[0]);
            }
          }
          update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_default_attributes', $new_defaults);
        }
      }
    }
```