# Showing 'Please choose product options…' on checkout page after clicks custom checkout button

Tags: wordpress, checkout

I have created custom checkout button in single product page. It is working fine.But after selected the variation with checkout button,it redirects to the checkout page with this error `'Please choose product options…'`.

**This is my code**

```
function add_content_after_addtocart() {
     global $woocommerce;
    // get the current post/product ID
    $current_product_id = get_the_ID();

    // get the product based on the ID
    $product = wc_get_product( $current_product_id );

    // get the "Checkout Page" URL
    $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();


    // run only on simple products 
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){

        ?>
        <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
    <?php /* if our custom button is clicked, append the string "&quantity=", and also the quantitiy number to the URL */ ?>

        // if our custom button is clicked
        $(".custom-checkout-btn").on("click", function() {

            // get the value of the "href" attribute 
            $(this).attr("href", function() {
                // return the "href" value + the string "&quantity=" + the current selected quantity number
                return this.href + '&quantity=' + $('input.qty').val();
            });

        });
    });
    </script>
        <?php
        echo '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="buy_now"><a href="'.$checkout_url.'?add-to-cart='.$current_product_id.'" class="single_add_to_cart_button buy_now_button button alt disabled custom-checkout-btn ajax_add_to_cart" >Buy Now</a></div></div><div class="clearfix"></div>';
?>

<?php
    }
    else if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){

       echo '</div><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="p-t-35"></div><div class="buy_now"><a href="'.$checkout_url.'?add-to-cart='.$current_product_id.'" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt buy_now_button button alt">Buy Now</a></div></div><div class="clearfix"></div>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart' );
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I had contacted WooThemes support team and they said that

> "We limit the amount of variations we show on the front end for speed.
>   But sometimes you need more than 36 variations, so we offer that
>   filter to override that limitation."

Please add this code below in the `functions.php` file.

```
  function custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold( $qty, $product ) 
    { 
    return 100;
     } 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: See this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111163/woocommerce-variable-product-notice-issue-please-choose-product-options

Comment: Please see this solution, I hope it will help you https://codeless.co/support/?topic=woocommerce-please-choose-product-options-error

Comment: not working actually. For simple products, the codes will work